# Grid (Serializer Grid) skip one record while loading

Tags: magento2, grid, php-7, grid-serlization

I am loading a serializer grid with record but it skips the very first record it is returning array correct

[image: Grid]

Code for my grid is working like this
->it loads the answer related to a question.
->the helper function returns an array related to a question the grid is suppose to load those answers in it.
->I have tried other ids it is working for other but when i pass id=1 helper data returns correct array but only one record is loaded but not the other one.

```
i.e for id=1
it returns =[1][2]
but grid only loads the [2] and skips [1]
```

My Grid Code is

```
namespace Vendor\NameSpace\Block\Adminhtml\Answer\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Vendor\NameSpace\Model\Topics\Attribute\Source\Status;


class Answer extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    protected $_answerFactory;

    protected $_HelperData;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Vendor\NameSpace\Model\AnswerFactory $answerFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Vendor\NameSpace\Helper\HelperData $HelperData,
        \Vendor\NameSpace\Model\ResourceModel\Answer $resourceAnswer,
        Status $status = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_answerFactory = $answerFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->resourceAnswer = $resourceAnswer;
        $this->_HelperData = $HelperData;
        $this->status = $status ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Status::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('answer_related_answer');
        $this->setDefaultSort('answer_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if($column->getId() == 'in_answer_related_answer')
        {
            $answerIds = $this->_getSelectedAnswer();
            if (empty($answerIds)) {
                $answerIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('answer_id', ['in' => $answerIds]);
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('answer_id', ['nin' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
            } elseif (!empty($answerIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('answer_id', ['nin' => $answerIds]);
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('answer_id', ['nin' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_answerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('answer_id', ['nin' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_answer_related_answer' => 1]);
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_answer_related_answer',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),   
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'name' => 'in_answer_related_answer',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedAnswer(),
                'index' => 'answer_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
            ]
        );
//        $this->addColumn(
//            'answer_id',
//            [
//                'header' => __('ID'),
//                'sortable' => true,
//                'index' => 'answer_id',
//                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
//                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
//            ]
//        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'answer',
            [
                'header' => __('Answer'),
                'index' => 'answer'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'answer_likes',
            [
                'header' => __('Answer Likes'),
                'index' => 'answer_likes'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'answer_dislikes',
            [
                'header' => __('Answer Dislikes'),
                'index' => 'answer_dislikes'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'answer_author',
            [
                'header' => __('Answer Author'),
                'index' => 'answer_author'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'answer_status',
            [
                'header' => __('Status'),
                'index' => 'answer_status',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->status->getOptionArray()
            ]

        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'action', [
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => ['base' => 'faq/answer/edit'],
                        'field' => 'id',
                    ],
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Delete'),
                        'url' => ['base' => 'faq/answer/delete'],
                        'field' => 'id',
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action',
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('faq/answer/answergrid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedAnswer()
    {
        $answer = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_answer');
        if ($answer === null)
        {
            return $answer = $this->_HelperData->getRelatedAnswerArray($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        }

        return $answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution I removed the

```
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('answer_id', ['nin' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
```

from my code now its working fine